# SSRS - Group set of rows based on calculated value from the row's data

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping, rdl

I want to group ( display ) a set of row(s) based on a calculation on one of row's column data.

Lets say I have 3 columns in my tablix.
1. Description
2. Amount
3. Debit/Credit

based on the D/C value I would like to sum up the amount ( for debit its -ve and credit is +ve) until the total gets to zero and then group those rows into a different color or a line space between other set of rows.

Example output:

---

Description         Amount               D/C

xyz                      10                      D

sss                      10                      C

abc                      15                      D

vvv                       5                       C

ccc                       5                       C

abc                       5                       C

Thanks 
Karthik

Comment: Do you want to group only when it sums to zero?

Comment: Did you set any Row Group in your tablix? I've seen a similar solution somewhere but it only works if no Row Groups have been set.

Comment: No I haven't done anything. my current tablix is simple one. All I need to represent the rows in that specific sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recreated your scenario using the dataset you have provided in the question.
I am using the Amount cell `background-color` property to group the sums.

This is the tablix I've created. The selected Cell background-property is set to a expression (see below):

[image]

In `Report` menu, `Report Properties...` / `Code` tab put this function in the text area.

```
Dim prevColor As String = "Red"
Dim accumulator As Double = 0
Public Function GetSumColor(ByVal value as Double) as String
    Dim color As String             
    accumulator = accumulator + value
    color = prevColor
    If accumulator = 0 Then
        If prevColor = "Red" Then
            prevColor = "Yellow"
        Else
            prevColor = "Red"
        End If
    End If
    Return color
End Function
```

This function will change the cell background color between `Red` or `Yellow` based on sums equals to zero (you can use the whatever color you want).

In the Amount cell background-color property use this expression:

```
=Code.GetSumColor(
IIF(Fields!D_C.Value="C",-Fields!Amount.Value,Fields!Amount.Value)
)
```

It will produce the following result:

[image]

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I tried with my report and I see everything Red. Not sure what is the change that I needed to do. checking on that now. otherwise your solutions looks good to me. 
The function call from the expression is giving error. =Code.GetSumColor...tells "unrecognized identifier". But I have the function code pasted on the report properties's code tab.

Comment: @Karthik Add an exact example of your data, it seems the function is not summing the values properly

Comment: Got it. I had to use Decimal data type in the function. Thanks a lot Alejandro